# Materialize CSS Modal shifts body contents to the right

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, materialize

I'm new here in this community.

**Main Contents :**

[image]

**Triggered Modal :**

[image]

The first picture shows the main contents of my page. The 2nd picture shows that the content (schedule card panel) extends/shifts to the right. CSS padding and overflow didn't solve my problem.

What should I do?

This is my complete CSS for this particular file:

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100vh;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-left: 240px;
    }
    main 
    {
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
    header
    {
        margin-bottom: 2% !important;
    }
    #nav-wrapper
    {
        padding-top: 0.4%;
        background-color: #1976d2 !important;
    }
    a .men
    {
        padding-top: 0.8%;
        font-size: 2.8rem;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) 
    {
     body 
     {
        padding-left: 0;
     }
    }

    ul .activeTab a
    {
        background-color: #ccc !important;
    }
    ul li a:hover
    {
        background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
    }
    .chPassHeader
    {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
</style>
```

This is my Modal

```
<!-- START : CHANGE PASSWORD MODAL-->
    <div id="chPassModal" class="modal animated fadeIn">

        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="chPassHeader"><i class="material-icons left">mode_edit</i> CHANGE PASSWORD</span>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <p>A bunch of text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="modal-action modal-close btn-flat">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END : CHANGE PASSWORD MODAL-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same problem. Shift content caused by giving body width in file "**materialize.js**" in function `openModal`.

```
 var openModal = function($trigger) {
      var $body = $('body');
      var oldWidth = $body.innerWidth();
      $body.css('overflow', 'hidden');

      $body.width(oldWidth);

      if ($modal.hasClass('open')) {
        return;
      }
```

The solution is to change

```
   $body.width(oldWidth)
```

into

```
   $body.width($(window).width());
```

Comment: I am using a slide out menu that is fixed on large screens. My solution was to comment out that line altogether

Answer (score 0):

I just commented this    `$body.width(oldWidth)` in materialize.js file and problem gone.

Comment: This is basically a worse copy of a proposed answer from a few months ago.